# (A better way to) Get files within a project using Eclipse and XText

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, xtext

I'm writing an XText editor, and doing some semantic highlighting. Part of the language I'm parsing refers to files, which should exist in the project. I'd like to highlight based on whether these files are in the correct place. At the moment, I've got a very ugly solution, and I'm sure there's a better way:

```
public void provideHighlightingFor( XtextResource resource, IHighlightedPositionAcceptor acceptor ) {
...
String resStr = resource.getURI().toString();
String projName = resStr.replaceAll( "^.*resource/", "" ).replaceAll( "/.*", "" );
IWorkspaceRoot workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFile file = workspace.getFile( new Path( projName + "/" + value ) );
ok = file != null && file.exists();
```

NOTE: "value" is a string which I've encountered when parsing, not the current file. I want to find out if {workspace}/{project}/{value} exists.

There must be a better way to get the project name/location, based on the current file; I've put this as an XText question, as I'd like, if possible, to avoid using the currently selected editor, and base selection on the current resource, which is presented as an XText resource.

NOTE: the code I've ended up using, based on the answer below is:

```
String platformString = resource.getURI().toPlatformString(true);
IFile myFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(platformString));
IProject proj = myFile.getProject();
IFile linkedFile = proj.getFile( value );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.toPlatformString(boolean)` and afterwards `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(platformString));`

something like

```
String platformString = resource.getURI().toPlatformString(true);
IFile myFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(platformString));
```

Comment: That gets me the string of the current file, but it doesn't help me get the project location without parsing that string. Apologies if the question wasn't clear, I've updated it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.. If you have the IFile you can get the project with IFile#getProject()

Comment: Thank you so much @TomSeidel! Exactly what I needed!