# Xtext get project root directory from validator

Tags: grammar, xtext, xtend

I need to get to validate existence of specific file in Xtext project. The file has similar path as validated object but other root directory, for example:

> $projPath/src/dir1/dir2/ValidatedFile.src
>
> $projPath/resources/dir1/dir2/SchoudBeExistFile.src

In validate function I get resource only with relative path (`/src/dir1/dir2/ValidatedFile.src`). But I don't know the project path, so I can't check existence of the `/resources/dir1/dir2/SchoudBeExistFile.src`.

Can you help me to find the absolute project path in validation function?

    `@Check
    def checkExternalFileExistance(MyType my) {
        val myTypeFullPath = ??
        val projectPath = ??
    }`

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Solved by adding `org.eclipse.core.resources` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin dependencies to xtext project via `plugin.xml` and using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242403/a-better-way-to-get-files-within-a-project-using-eclipse-and-xtext) solution in grammar style. No absolute path required for this.

```
@Check
def checkExternalFlowDirExistance(MyType my) {
    val platformString = my.eResource.URI.toPlatformString(true);
    val myFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(platformString));
    val proj = myFile.getProject();
    val shouldExistsFile = proj.geFile("/resources/dir1/dir2/SchoudBeExistFile.src")
    if (!shouldExistsFile.exists) {
    // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the full path from the Resource:

```
@Check
def checkEventFileNameEqualsEventName(Mytype my){
    val myTypeFullPath=my.eResource.URI.toPlatformString(true)
}
```

Comment: This expression returns me relative to project root path including the project dir, like "/MyPoj/src/package/MyType.mylang". I need absolute path to use in "new File(absolutePath).exists()"